# How to remove price from woo-commerce processing order email.?

Tags: woocommerce

[image]

How to remove the above column.

so that customer should call for price  of the item they are interested in.

Comment: You want people to order stuff first, and then they have to call to find out how much they actually have to pay only later? In what scenario does that makes sense (and would be legal) ...?

Comment: Yes Cbore, That is what my client requirement is. It is only for enquiry purpose. there will be no transaction. Later all other processes are taken care by client through call.

Comment: Well then go check the email templates of woocommerce.